# executor pool in a java server

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, executorservice

I m having a java server which is processing images as in the web pages requested by the client.

Now processing these images requires time and memory and n number of threads going into the processing images hangs the server.

Now for avoiding the situation the code which processes the images, i have put them inside a Runnable class and calling them from a executor pool.

My question is if the below implementation is right approach to execute the Executor pool in a server.

The Runnable class being -

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     private final String id;

    MyRunnable(String tid) {
        this.id = tid;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        NewAlbumImage nai = new NewAlbumImage();                
        nai.save_image(id,false);        
    }
}
```

The code which runs the Runnable class is as below -

```
newa.NewClass newca = new newa.NewClass();
Runnable mr = new MyRunnable(id);
newca.executor.execute(mr);
```

The class NewClass has a static executor variable -

```
static ExecutorService executor;
```

I m initializing the executor variable at the web applictation startup and destroying the same at the web application close -

```
public class AppNameServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Initializing Executor Pool");
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();
    nc.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);


}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    NewClass nc = new NewClass();
    nc.executor.shutdown();
    try {
        nc.executor.awaitTermination( 10L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println("Executor Pool await Termination exception");
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that

> The class NewClass has a static executor variable - 
>   static ExecutorService executor;

I suggest to use

```
NewClass.executor.execute(yourRunnableInstance);

NewClass.executor.shutdown();
```

This will be easy to figure out that `executor` is a static field, you don't need to create multiple `NewClass` instances.

The rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: If I shutdown the executor then where do I initialize it?

Comment: Im saying the static fields is better to be invokded by class name, not create a new class instance, that will make people confused:)  `NewClass.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);`  `newFixedThreadPool()` is a static factory method, it will initialize a new `ExecutorService` instance for you.

Comment: If 10 threads (page requests) initialiaze the same static variable and execute and shutdown would'nt it cause problems?

Comment: it will. my point is when using static field, call it using the class name, no matter it is a new instance call the field or the class name, the threads issue will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things I would consider.

First, your executor is static.  I'd use some sort of dependency injection framework to properly inject your the executor where needed. OR add it as an attribute in your servlet context and inject it yourself when the servlet initializes.

Create/Shutdown using the ServletContext:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
    context.setAttribute("executor", Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
    ExecutorService executor = (ExecutorService)context.getAttribute("executor");
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Secondly, you are using a fixed thread pool. This is a possible bottleneck (but maybe it's deliberate to save the CPU?). If there's no way more that 10 images could be resized at the same time, you're fine. But if the rate at which they are being processed is slower than the rate that requests are coming in, you are going to find that a fixed thread pool is not going to work.  In fact, if your application joins on the resizing task for the response back to the user, you've limited the number of possible request at any given moment to the number of threads defined.  Try using a cached thread pool. Threads are created on demand and die from inactivity.

```
Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

Lastly, and I think this is more important, how is you application going to scale?  The more users you have, the more images that are going to be processed on your web-server. Your response time is going to degrade very quickly. As few as three users trying to resize images at the same time could use 100% of your CPU. I'd suggest farming out your image resizing to another machine, one more capable.

Comment: _But if the rate at which they are being processed is slower than the rate that requests are coming in, you are going to find that a fixed thread pool is not going to work_. 
I had known if this happens the page is going to wait till the executor has not finished with processing the image.